# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Tags: dired, ssh, shell-command

CentOS 7,  Emacs 27.1

Here content of file **myFile.sh**:

```
ssh myuser@10.111.11.111
```

So when in **vterm** mode I use this:

```
./myFile.sh
```

then I success connect to the remote machine (ip = 10.111.11.111) by Tramp mode.

Nice.

Now I want to run **myFile.sh** in **dired** mode.
Here folder with myFile.sh in dired mode.

[image]

So I try

```
! (dired-do-shell-command)
```

As result in the minibuffer show.

[image]

Then in the minibuffer I input

```
./myFile.sh
```

and press **Enter**.

But I get error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

[image]

Comment: Executing `./myfile.sh` from a vterm does not mean you are using Tramp to connect to the remote: all it means is that you have an ssh connection to the remote, the same as if you were doing it in a terminal outside of emacs. If you want to open a Tramp connection, then just do `C-x C-f /scp:myuser@10.111.11.111:` or something similar.

Comment: @NickD I know about Tramp connection. But I want run my bash file in dired mode (by "! (dired-do-shell-command)") . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the arguments "-t -t" to your ssh call (yes, "-t" twice).

Comment: I edit myfile.sh like this: ssh -t -t myuser@10.111.11.111   . But it not help. Same result.

Comment: Hmm, then I cannot help. Use Tramp :-)